# Trigger error SQL 1242 (Palabras reservadas NEW & OLD)

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

A continuación os voy a adjuntar una imagen sobre la BBDD sobre la que estoy trabajando para realizar el trigger y os empiezo a contar[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno, la idea era crear un trigger que al yo meter todos los datos de un pedido me diese el subtotal, con la siguiente formula:
"Pedido.subtotal= (viaje.precio+clase.precio)*Pedido.pasajeros;"

He intentado hacer el trigger de varias maneras, he ido avanzando entre distintos errores y ahora estoy estancado con el 1242. Creo que he de usar las palabras claves NEW y OLD, pero no se ni como ni donde meterlas.
Por último os dejo el último trigger que he intentado:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `pedidos_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `pedidos` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
declare final integer;
declare vprecio integer;
declare cprecio integer;
declare passengers integer;

set @final:= (select subtotal from pedidos);
set @vprecio:= (select precio from viajes);
set @cprecio:= (select precio from clase);
set @pass:= (select pasajeros from pedidos);

    SET @final = (@vprecio+@cprecio)*@pass;
END
```

Comment: Puedes añadir un ejemplo de datos y del resultado que quieres obtener. NEW y OLD se utilizan para a ceder a los datos de la consulta y fila sobre la que está actuando el trigger

Comment: Yo inserto los datos de las claves foraneas es decir: viaje(varchar) y clase(varchar). Con estas accedo a los precios que tienen guardados en otras tablas y por ultimo multiplico los pasajeros que son un campo de la tabla pedidos